# $w$ is exact implies $\int_\gamma w=0$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, riemannian-geometry

> Let $A$ be a path-connected set of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and let $w\in\Omega^1(A)$ be a differential form of degree 1. The following conditions are equivalent:
>
> (i) $w$ is exact.
>
> (ii)Any curve $\gamma$ of $C^1$ class, closed in $A$, then
>
> $\int_\gamma w=0$

The definition of a exact differential form I have is the following:"*$w$ is an exact differential form if there is $f\in C^{k+1}(M,\mathbb{R})$ such as $df=w$. And f is called the primitive of $w$".*

I know from another proposition that if $w$ is an exact differential form $\int_\gamma w=f(\gamma(b))-f(\gamma(a))$.

However I cannot see how condition (i) implies (ii). The fact $w$ is exact does not necessarily implies $w$ to be $0$.

**Question:**

How can it be proved condition (i) implies (ii)?

Comment: What happens if $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$ in the last formula you mentioned?

Comment: @SangchulLee It would be zero, if $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$.However the proposition states "any curve $\gamma$". So I think I cannot assume $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$.

Comment: I was thinking you only need to care about *closed curves*...

Comment: What does  a closed curve mean? I do not know the definition of a closed curve. Does it mean the starting point is the ending point so therefore it is closed?

Comment: Yes, that is the definiton of a closed curve.